# Searching for particular files in a directory non-recursively using find. AIX

Tags: unix, aix

I have a script which has the following command. I am trying to edit this in such a way that it only searches the files in the directory of the path without going in the subdirectories. That is not recursive search

find {Path} -name "cor*" -type f -exec ls -l {} \;

Example: The command should give cor123.log only and not cor456.log. Currently it gives both

```
<Path>
     ..cor123.log
    <directory>
      ..cor456.log
```

I tried using -maxdepth but it's not supported in AIX. -prune and -depth didn't help either.

Will appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
find . -name . -o -prune
```

to find files and directories non-recursively.

So in your case this one will work:

```
find . -name . -o -prune -name 'cor*' -type f -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Comment: I tried this it didn't work. Didn't return any files

Comment: Did you substitute the dot with your actual path? And does the first example work at your environment?

Comment: Yes, I substituted the dot (the one after find) but didn't get the result. The first command didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need `find` for selecting files only?
When you know that all files starting with `cor` are regula files, you can use
`ls -l ${Path}/cor*`
or
`ls -l ${Path}/cor*.log`

When you need the `-type f`, you can try to filter the results.
The filename can not have a `/`, so remove everything with an `/` after the Path.
We do not know the last char of ${Path}. It can be `/`, which will make the `grep -Ev "${Path}/.*/"` filter useless. After the Path at least one character is needed before looking for the next `/`.

```
find "${Path}" -name "cor*" -type f 2>/dev/null| grep -Ev "${Path}..*/" | xargs -ls
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but may save some. In aix

```
find /some/directory/* -prune -type f -name *.log
```

For instance make your path have the last forward slash with a wildcard then -prune

> /*

```
find /some/directory/* -prune -name "cor*" -type f -exec ls -l {} \
```

Tested.